# part of speech of "all" in "it all went wrong"

Tags: pronouns, parts-of-speech

Do you think "all" is a pronoun or adverb in "It all went wrong"?

Is the "all" identical to the "all" in "Tom removed them all"?

Comment: *It went all wrong.* There **all** is an adverb. *It all went wrong*. There **all** is something else, and is related in some way to **it** not to the verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (1) *It all went wrong*, *all* would be a determinative functioning as quantificational adjunct in clause structure (quantifying the subject). In (2) *Tom removed them all*, *them all* is a compound pronoun (there are only 6, it seems, *us*/*you*/*them* *all*/*both*) functioning as object.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston, Pullum, et al. (2002) essentially provides a test (on p.428) to distinguish the two: (1) allows an adjunct to be inserted between the pronoun and the quantificational adjunct (*It **certainly** all went wrong*) and the pronoun can be replaced by NPs with common noun heads (***The experiments*** all went wrong) – (2) doesn't permit this, with both **Tom removed them **certainly** all* and **Tom removed **the girls** all* being ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

In the meaning 'it all = all things' it's an *adjective*, at least dictionaries put the examples like 'all things (men, etc)' and 'all his life' in the section where 'all' is treated as an adjective..